# A button containing a flex-grow image

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I'm trying to create a button with an image stacked vertically on top of some text. The image is SVG and the button has a fixed height. I'd like to set the size of the image based on flex-grow, so it gets as tall as it can (and scales its width proportionately). For some reason, when I do this, the button's width does not stretch to contain the image:

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brezxdj7/1/)

```
<button>
  <img src="http://svgur.com/i/gGN.svg" />
  <label>Click me</label>
</button>
```

```
button
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

img
{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Try changing the button sizing from `height: 200px;` to `width:200px;`. `flex-grow` affects the direction you've specified which in this case is the column so the svg isn't going to increase in size because it's already filled its own proportional height of the container per your height attribute.

Comment: @AStombaugh I'm not sure if I explained the problem correctly. The button is supposed to be a specific height. The image is displaying at the size I expect, the thing that's wrong here is that the button's width hasn't stretched to contain it.

Comment: you could set the width and height explicitly, in this case to 200px, so that the image is contained inside of the button but you would need to do some styling for your label. Is there a particular reason you're using a flexbox for a button? Flexboxes are generally used to contain and layout items, like buttons, but I don't think I've ever seen a button styled using a flexbox. Are you trying to make the button scaleable or just contain the graphic itself?

Comment: @AStombaugh I want to have a fixed-height button with an image up top and a label at the bottom, and the key is that the image should be as big as it can be without pushing the label out of the button. As far as I know, flex-grow is the only way of getting this fill-remaining-space behavior without having to hard-code in specific sizes of things.

Comment: The flex-grow is doing what you're asking it to do though. If you remove it from your image you'll notice everything scales back down to fit the unspecified width of the button. You've told it to grow, and it will, based on the `flex-direction` property which in this case is a column with a set height of 200px. You've already gotten into hard-coding values at this point so you’ll need some sort of width or max-width attribute somewhere.

Comment: @AStombaugh Like I said, flex-grow is indeed doing what I want - the image is the size I want it to be. I just want the button to get wider.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to give your `<img>` both `width` and `max-height` properties:

```css
button
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

label{
}

img
{
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width:100%;
  height:80%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="http://svgur.com/i/gGN.svg" />
  <label>Click me</label>
</button>
```

But you'll certainly need some width or height applied on you image – otherwise your image will be rendered with some default dimensions.

Comment: Strangely, this works on Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: @Jack M: edited the snippet and changed width and heights – seems to work also in firefox.